Convert pyclass instance to PyObject
If I have an instance of some struct that derives from #[pyclass] how do I convert it to a PyObject. I know conceptually that I need to convert the Rust struct struct to a Python  object, obtain the GIL, and then put the object on the garbage collector. Obviously, PyO3 has the capability to do this, I just don't know how to invoke it.
use pyo3::exceptions::PyTypeError;
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass(extends=PyTypeError]
pub struct Foo {
    bar: PyObject,
    baz: PyObject,
}

impl Foo {
    fn fun(self, py: Python) -> PyObject {
        // What to put here?
    }
}

I thought that the pyclass macro was supposed to automatically add the into_pyobject method, but the compiler says that self has no such method.

Note that you're not supposed to make a pyclass that inherits from PyTypeError directly, instead you should use create_exception!().

The correct way to do that is as follows:
use pyo3::exceptions::PyTypeError;
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass(extends=PyTypeError)]
pub struct Foo {
    bar: PyObject,
    baz: PyObject,
}

impl Foo {
    fn fun(this: Bound<'_, Self>) -> PyObject {
        this.into_any().unbind()
    }
}

You can take Bound<'_, Self> in methods in #[pymethods] blocks instead of self.

What if I don't have control over the signature? For example, if I am trying to implement the PyErrArguments  trait?

@drhagen That probably means you're holding it wrong.

Because you used extends, that disabled the implementation of the IntoPyObject trait which adds the into_pyobject method to the class. Fortunately, there is a derive macro for IntoPyObject, so it is easy to add it back in.
This does not appear to be documented in the pyclass macro or in IntoPyObject. Even putting the default extends=PyAny disables IntoPyObject.
Once you have into_pyobject, it is a relatively straightforward implementation to convert to a PyObject.
use pyo3::exceptions::PyTypeError;
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::IntoPyObject;

#[pyclass(extends=PyTypeError)]
#[derive(IntoPyObject)]
pub struct Foo {
    bar: PyObject,
    baz: PyObject,
}

impl Foo {
    fn fun(self, py: Python) -> PyObject {
        self.into_pyobject(py).unwrap().into()
    }
}


That creates a copy of the object, which probably isn't what you want.

@ChayimFriedman Am I wrong in my belief that, obviously, there has to be one copy to go from a Rust memory layout to a Python memory layout.? I thought that conversion formed the entire basis of PyO3. Is there a second copy happening?

pyclasses are usually stored in Python memory (although they can also be stored outside of it) and the Rust memory is just reference to that. So no, no copy is needed.
